# How to autopopulate existing taxonomy terms' description?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I'd like to write a function that autopopulate existing taxonomy terms description with given text patterns.
(It would be ice on the cake if newly created tax.terms's description were autopopulated too.)
For example: custom post type - recipe,
taxonomy         - cusine,
taxonomy terms   - italian,
- american,
- mexican,

```
        description for cuisine: %taxonomy term name% some text %taxonomy term name% some text.
        output: -italian some text italian some text.
                -american some text american some text.
                -mexican some text mexican some text.
```

Recipes are classified by taxonomy terms and are driven by tanonomy.php

That's what I've done so far.

```
function kt_add_tax_description() {
    
        $kt_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
        $kt_term_id = $kt_term->term_id;
        $kt_term_name = $kt_term->name;
        $kt_term_description = $kt_term->description;
        
        if(is_tax('cuisine') && $kt_term_description == ''){

            $kt_meta_value = "<p>$kt_term_name text text text text!</p><h2>$kt_term_name</h2>";

            
            update_term_meta( $kt_term_id, 'description', $kt_meta_value );
        }

        if(is_tax('course')){
    
            $kt_meta_value = "<p>$kt_term_name text text text text! $kt_term_name text text.</p> 
                              <h2>$kt_term_name</h2>";

            
            update_term_meta( $kt_term_id, 'description', $kt_meta_value );
        }
       
       (more tax)
       .
       .
       .
 
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','kt_add_tax_description');
```

I got this error:

Notice: Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object in /home/cghonlap/kt-gp-premium.cg-honlap.hu/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 173

Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /home/cghonlap/kt-gp-premium.cg-honlap.hu/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 174

Notice: Trying to get property 'description' of non-object in /home/cghonlap/kt-gp-premium.cg-honlap.hu/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 175

What can be the problem(s)?

I do not even now if it is the right aproach to achieve my goal.